# ¿Cómo enviar e ingresar datos de arreglos de inputs clonados por $_POST a una BD?

Tags: php, javascript, post, array

Tengo un formulario que contiene inputs que se clonan a través de botones, los botones de los signos más (+) y menos (-), clonan y eliminan respectivamente los input de label “marca y valor” y el botón de agregar clona todo el conjunto incluyendo el input de label “articulo”.

He colocado nombres a los inputs de tal manera que sean del tipo array, la condición es que “articulo” sea un arreglo que contenga a “marca y valor”.

Al clonar el conjunto, cada input de “articulo”, tiene sus propios valores de “marca y valor”, la condición es que “articulo” sea un arreglo que contenga a “marca y valor”, o sea cada arreglo “articulo” contiene distintos arreglos de marca y valor, según se clone los inputs.

```js
$(function(){
            $(document).on('click',"#agregartablauno" , function(){                
            $("#tablauno tbody tr:eq()").clone(false)
                .append('<td class="eliminartablauno"><input type="button" value="ELIMINAR"/></td>')
                .appendTo("#tablauno");         
            });

            $(document).on("click",".eliminartablauno",function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).remove();
            });

            $(this).on('click', ".agregartablados" , function(){                
            $(".tablados tbody tr:eq()").clone()
                .append('<td class="eliminartablados"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>')
                .appendTo(".tablados");         
            });

            $(document).on("click",".eliminartablados",function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $(parent).remove();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>I</title>
    <script>    
    </script>
</head>
<body><center>
<form method="POST" action="ClonProducto1.php">    
   <table id="tablauno" align="center" >
     <tr>
       <td>
        ARTICULO <input class="nom" type="text" name="form[txtarticulo][]" size=32 />
       </td>                                         
       <td>
        <table class="tablados">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                 <td>MARCA</td>
                 <td>VALOR</td>
              </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <tr id="filas-base">
                  <td><input id="txtmarca" name="form[txtmarca][]" type="text" /></td>
                  <td><input id="txtvalor" name="form[txtvalor][]" type="text" /></td> 
               </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table> 
        <input class="agregartablados" type="button" value="+" /> 
      </td>            
    </tr>
   </table>
   <input id="agregartablauno" type="button" value="AGREGAR"> <br><br>
<input name="enviar" type="submit" value=" Enviar ">
</form>  
</center></body>
</html>
```

Por ejemplo en este caso he clonado dos inputs “artículo”, para articulo1 hay 2 marcas y un valor por cada marca respectivamente, para articulo2 hay 3 marcas y un valor por cada marca igualmente.

[image: Por ejemplo en este caso he clonado dos inputs “artículo”, para articulo1 hay 2 marcas y un valor por cada marca respectivamente, para articulo2 hay 3 marcas y un valor por cada marca igualmente.]

Al enviar el formulario se almacena de la siguiente forma en la base de datos, sin hacer diferenciación para cada “articulo”.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que he utilizado en el archivo que recibe $_POST

```html
<?php
include conexion.php;
$articulo = $_REQUEST['form'];
foreach($articulo['txtarticulo'] as $llave => $nom_art ) {
    foreach ($articulo['txtmarca'] as $llave => $marca){
            $valor = $articulo['txtvalor'][$llave];            
            $datoUnico[] = '("'.$nom_art.'", "'.$marca.'","'.$valor.'" )';            
        $insertar = "INSERT INTO articulos VALUES " . implode(', ',$datoUnico);
    }
}
if(mysql_query($insertar)) { die('<BR>'.'INGRESO CON EXITO'); }
?>
```

¿Cómo podría cambiar en el código para que me ingrese en la BD, diferenciando los “artículos” con sus marcas y valores respectivos?.

Una alternativa que probe fue la de cambiar algunos indices en el HTML de los inputs de la siguiente manera:

```
<input class="nom" type="text" name="form[]" size=32 />
<input id="txtmarca" name="form[][txtmarca]" type="text" />
<input id="txtvalor" name="form[][txtvalor]" type="text" />
```

el respectivo rrecorrido con el foreach lo realize asi para este cambio en los names de los inputs:

```html
<?php
$articulo = $_REQUEST['form'];
foreach($articulo as $llave => $nom_art ) {
$nom_art1=implode(',',$nom_art);
echo "<br>".$nom_art1;
}
?>
```

El rrecorrido lo hace, pero ahora no se como insertarlo en la BD, arriba indique como era la tabla donde se almacenan estos datos, anteriormente antes de insertarlo armaba un arreglo con los datos que recibia del $_POST y luego lo ingresaba, ahora tengo el problema para armar este arreglo con el orden mencionado antes "cada articulo tiene su(s) propia(s) marca(s) con un unico valor para cada marca(s)".

Comment: Lo más sencillo es poner un índice en el html que relacione él artículos con las marcas y modelos, al crear una nueva opción tendrá que recibir ese índice.

Comment: Coloque los indices en el HTML de la siguiente manera para relacionar "articulo" con cada "marca y valor respectivo":

Comment: Para articulo <input  type="text" name="form[]" />, para marca : <input type="text" name="form[][txtmarca]"  /> y para valor : <input type="text" name="form[][txtvalor]"  />, modificando en el archivo HTML que clona los inputs al hacer un print_r=($_POST)  logre algo de lo que queria, PERO ya al rrecorrer con foreach hay problemas con los indices vacios de marca y valor.